# Linker error LNK2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have the following files

file1_moduleA.hpp

file1_moduleA.cpp

sharedFile.hpp

file1_moduleB.cpp

```
//sharedFile.hpp
extern CustomClass *doSomething(CustomClass *var1, const char *var2);
extern CustomClass *doSomethingElse(const char *var1);

template <class MYCLASS_A>
void myFunction(CustomClass *var1, const char* var2){
assert(somthing);
if (condition){
    new (MYCLASS_A);
}
}



//file1_moduleA.cpp
#include "sharedFile.hpp"
// Contains the definitions of doSomething and doSomethingElse among others


//file1_moduleA.hpp
// Other declarations


//file1_moduleB.cpp
#include"sharedFile.hpp"

//...SNIPPETS OF CODE
void someFunction(CustomClass* var1){
doSomething(var1, "FOO");
}
//...
```

The following are in one Visual Studio Project, Project A:
file1_moduleA.hpp, file1_moduleA.cpp and sharedFile.hpp

The following are in another VS Project, Project B:
file1_moduleB.cpp, file1_moduleB.hpp

Project A compiles and links perfectly, whereas Project B compiles but gives an unresolved symbol for **CustomClass *doSomething(CustomClass *var1, const char *var2)** at **someFunction in file1_moduleB.cpp**

I have tried **defining** the function with and without extern; tried using a separate file for the template in file1_moduleA.hpp; tried inducing dependency between ProjectB and ProjectA in VS, but nothing seems to work. I am unsure why the definition is not being found during linking. ProjectA.lib however, is being created.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using visual studio, and these are different project, then make project B dependent upon project A.

Right click on the solution.
Go to project dependencies.

Choose Project B.

Click Project A (making project B dependent upon Project A)

rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include shared file in project B?

Comment: No, I did not include the file. I included the sharedFile.hpp in the files in project B.

And I don't think I should I have to. Including sharedFile.hpp forces me to include some other files as well and I might as well leave it as one project.